# when you navigate to another part within the app when you click the browser's back button the page just refreshes, it doesn't go back

Tags: angularjs, routes

firstly, thank you guys.
I have an angular app and I'm using anchor links all over. the app is just 5 pages, but each page has links to other parts within the same page and my main nav can navigate you to another anchor on another page.

My problem is, when you navigate to another part within the app when you click the browser's back button the page just refreshes, it doesn't go back. What is causing that and how to fix this problem?

Thanks again guys.

js:

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$routeParams', function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
}]);
```

I also have routes, but they're just usual routes

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="about?scrollTo=our-doctor">OUR DOCTOR</a></li>
  <li><a href="about?scrollTo=our-practice">OUR PRACTICE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I get you don't change the URL. But please, provide your code.

Comment: angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$routeParams', function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
}]);

Comment: Instead of adding code in comments you should edit the question to include necesary code

Comment: Yeh I realized that and I went in and edit the question, thanks. So the question is updated